# $("form").valid() throwing error, though all files included in layout

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I am getting a "Object doesn't support property or method 'valid'" error throwing at the line where I am calling the valid method for my form.

```
$('#NewPersonForm').valid();
```

I checked if any stray/missed  semicolons or commas, but everything seems fine. I have included the follwing scripts in my _layout.cshtml file

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/CustomizeTelerikGridFilter.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Common.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/CustomValidator.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Appreciate any thoughts please.

**EDIT**

Complete script references did not get pasted. Also I tried the same in IE, CHROME, FF

Comment: Thanks gdron, I have already spent hours to figure out whats going wrong. I have googled and seens n number of tutorials and pages for no help :(

Comment: I put my money on that you're referencing the JQuery scripts again, thus overrding the `validation` plugin. check the rendered HTML, you probably have two references to `JQUERY`

Comment: Add the rendered HTML and let us see.

Comment: The HTML is very huge shall i upload it somewhere so that you can have a look

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I put my money on this option:
You are referencing the `JQuery` scripts again in the page, thus overriding the `validation` plugin declared in the `_layout.cshtml`.

JQuery plugins extends the `JQuery` object, So if you reference JQuery again it overrides the "extended" JQuery object.

Check the rendered HTML, you probably have two references to `JQuery` library

Comment: He already has it included. Just scroll on the right in the scripts he has shown in the question. I agree, it's a mess. He should have split them on new lines for more readability.

Comment: Hi Gdron, I just edited my post, the text did not copy for some reason correctly. I have added them all

Comment: @gdoron : oh boy ! jquery-1.5.1.min.js is referenced in my html rendered by the telerik control. Could this be an issue ?

Comment: @Anand. If it's referenced after the `validation` in the layout, then We have a winner. **jackpot**

Comment: @gdoron: so basically after i register the scripts as above , again the jquery-1.5.1.min.js is registered....

Comment: @gdoron : THANKS A TON ! that indeed no doubt is the issue. I rendered without the telerik controls registering jquery again and it works like a charm :)

I have burnt hours onto this thing. :)n hope this saves someone else's

Comment: Yes! Accidentally adding jquery.js again definitely broke my validation. Removing the second reference fixed it.