# Shining Image jquery plugin not work

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am using [Shining Image jQuery plugin](http://www.biscay-charly.com/_plugins/plug_shiningImage/) for some images in my project .
when using it with a selector like `$('#logo').shiningImage();` i get an error that say:

> Object [object Object] has no method 'shiningImage'

what is problem. please help me if know!

Comment: How can anyone help based on so little information?  Please provide more code, a link to your page or a demo.  Did you **[purchase](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-shining-image/711157), download and install** the plugin on your page?

Comment: Have you included the plugin on the page with: <script src="PATH TO SCRIPT" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: provide your html, it looks like you may not be including the plugin file correctly.

Comment: @Sparky672 My mind still boggles at the entire concept of buying JavaScript code.

Comment: @mblase75, Yes, although Nivo for Wordpress costs $ as does FancyBox for a business site.

Comment: no ! i did not purchase it. i using from [link](http://www.biscay-charly.com/_plugins/plug_shiningImage/js/jquery.shiningImage.min.js)  address directly.:)

Comment: @Ahmad ... you know that's illegal, right?

Comment: @jbabey No, it's a license violation, which isn't the same thing at all.

Comment: "If you make other use of the Sites, or the Products, content, code, data or materials on the Sites or available through the Sites, except as otherwise provided above, you will violate copyright and other laws of Australia, other countries, as well as applicable state laws and may be subject to liability for such unauthorised use." http://codecanyon.net/legal/user

Comment: It's a license violation and it's a copyright violation.  The latter is illegal in most countries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you have a reference to it so this is probably the issue:

You are referencing the `JQuery` scripts again in the page, thus overriding the `Shining Image` plugin which declared before the second reference.

JQuery plugins extends the `JQuery` object, So if you reference JQuery again it overrides the "extended" JQuery object.

Check the rendered HTML, you probably have two references to `JQuery` library

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9061371/601179) question, I adjust my answer a bit, it looks like the same problem

Or you just added the reference to the plugin before add the reference to the `JQuery` it self, which explains why you're having problems...