# Javascript plugins not working (beside or not beside jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a webpage which uses jquery.transit plugin.
I download the .js file and included it. I also included jquery.js.
These files are located in a folder called Scripts.
Now when i click on a button that makes a div object move, nothing happens.
I'm using Aptana version 3 installed on Microsoft windows platform.
Most of plugins don't work.
My first guess was if I'm using jquery beside other jquery plugins I should do some syntax operations but in one of my jquery plugins it proved wrong.
now my question is what is the standard way of doing this and down here is my code so if it has a problem ,I'd be happy if anyone help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/Scripts/jquery.transit.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
 </head>
 <body>  
    <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="$('#movDiv').transition({ rotate: '30deg' });"> Click Me </button>
    <div id="movDiv"></div>
 </body>
```

Comment: try removing the "/" in front of Scripts if the Scripts folder is located in the same directory as the html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem a lot of people are doing:

You should reference jQuery library **once** and above all other jQuery plugins.
If you reference jQuery again it will override every earlier plugin.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9061371/601179) question, you are might facing the same problem.

---

**Update:**

Steps:

- **1.** Reference jQuery library in highest place in the `<head>`
- **2.** Don't reference it again.
- **3.** Reference all your plugins after the jQuery library.

I Hope I'm clear enough.

Comment: OK, How can I do that in Aptana? or should I do it in Aptana or just small change in html code?

Comment: @user1290467. I added the steps to make my answer extremely easy to understand.

Comment: Yes, but I have several pages and in one of them I'm want to use jquery.transit

Comment: @user1290467. Are you using some sort of masterpage or layout? Where do you reference jQuery?

Comment: No ,I'm not using masterpage or layout.

Comment: @user1290467. O.K. so just reference in that page the plugin after jQuery. **What is the problem?**

Comment: all-right, I have a page named myblog.html and in that page I have a div which I want to apply animation effects on it. now ,In my index.html page everything is working great but in my myblog.html page I can't apply 'jquery.transmit' effects even if I do or do not refrence the jquery.transmit plugin.

Comment: @user1290467. Show the source code of `myblog.html`. and make sure you have a reference to jQuery **and** to the plugin you're using.

Comment: @user1290467. Your problem isn't with the plugins. The references to scripts are wrong. so the links are broken. `http://neemasakhtemani.com/Scripts/jquery.transit.js` is not found, so as `http://neemasakhtemani.com/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js` fix the links and you're good.