# asp.net content pages and jquery plugins

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am having issues with using the jQuery masked input plugin within a content page. It works fine in a normal web form but does not recognise the plugin within a content page.
this is the plugin: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

here is a basic sample content page :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="masterContent.aspx.cs" Inherits="Dating.TEST.masterContent" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            //$('#<%= TextBox3.ClientID %>').mask("(999) 9999-9999");
            $("#TextBox3").mask("(999) 9999-9999");
        });

    </script>  

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
           <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>             
</asp:Content>
```

when i debug this i get this error : "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'mask'"

I have tried everything i can think of but it only seems to work in webforms.

Comment: Are you sure the the javascript file for the plugin loaded correctly?

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061407/601179)

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. yes it works fine in the webforms but wont work in the content even if i drag it from the solution explorer

Comment: can you try to load jqueries in master page's head.

Comment: Any chance that you are already including jquery or the maskedinput js file on the master page as well? Meaning they are being added twice?

Comment: Hi i tried both of those suggestions before posting. the masterpage is unchanged from the Site.Master that is in the web application template. the only change is i added the bootstrap css link. I will try again this time with everything in the master page tonight, but when i was testing last night the html output that is generated looks correct. everything is in the Head tags in the correct order with no duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing is happening because the jquery.maskedinput-1.3.js and / or jquery-1.8.2.min.js are not being loaded successfully.

Check the location of these files is correct relative to the page you are loading.